# .Net 6.0 Configuration files

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0

Been getting a app that serves up data to a VBA application.  Now at point trying to get configuration files (appsettings.json & appsettings.Development.Json). Right now it's a .net6.0 console app, later I'm making it an IconTrayApp.

Ran into a problem, the main Program.cs method gets the appsettings.json and the worker gets the appssettings.Developement.json. I understand why Main() get the none environment json, because I explicitly load it.  But I want the app to use the same file both in an out of the IDE.

here is program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using PostDataService.InterfaceModels;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using System;

namespace PostDataService
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
      IConfiguration config = builder.Build();
      string _logFQN = config["PostConfig:Basefolder"] + config["PostConfig:LogsFolder"] + config["PostConfig:LogFname"];
      string _LogTemplate = config["PostConfig:LogTemplate"];

      var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithThreadId()
        .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
        .WriteTo.File(_logFQN,
        fileSizeLimitBytes: 524288000,
        rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
        outputTemplate: _LogTemplate);

      Log.Logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
      try
      {
        Log.Write(LogEventLevel.Information, "Start USPS Data Server");
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
      }
      finally
      {
        Log.Information("USPS Server stopped");
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
      }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
              IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
              WorkerOptions options = configuration.GetSection("PostConfig").Get<WorkerOptions>();
              services.AddSingleton(options);
              services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });

  }
}
```

and here is appsettings.json (appsettings.Development.json)

```json
{
  "PostConfig": {
    "BaseFolder": "./App_Data/",
    "LogsFolder": "logs/",
    "SystemFQN": "C:/Test/PostalDB/PostalData.db",
    "CustFQN": "C:/Test/PostalDB/PostalCustomer.db",
    "LogFname": "USPS_.log",
    "LogTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}\t{EnvironmentUserName}\t[{Level:u4}]\t<{ThreadId}>\t{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
  }
}
```

I did try and use the .AddEnvironmentVariables() in the configuration builder and that did not seem to change things. I suspect because of the explicit addjsonfile call.

Comment: `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);`?

Comment: @guru;  env.EnvironmentName does not exist more specifically env is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have been a bit unclear, the Worker gets the appsettings.Development.json file which is correct as I'm running in VS.  What I'm looking for is a clean way to get same behavior within the Main() method.

I've taken Guru Stron's comment and forced it to include the appsettings.dev... file as follows:

```
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environments.Development}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

It seems to work ok just feels like I'm hard coding something that should be baked in.

Also if I run the application from the Windows File Explorer I get the appsettings.developement.json values in the main but the appsettings.json in the worker class.  THis makes sense as the file appsettings.development.json overrides appsettings.json per the builder calls.  Not ideal.

Comment: This is basically what default configuration registration does for ASP.NET Core (it also adds some other sources).  [Related](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#json-configuration-provider)

Answer (score 0):

In a console application, I suggest incorporating configuration as a service, using the dependency injection services available in `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`. This service comes pre-packaged in ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET Web App templates. This approach enables easy re-use of components and services across your applications, simplifies unit testing, and aids in implementing a significant amount of sample code published for these platforms.

The following is a basic implementation in C# console application, in Program.cs

```cs
//Add these packages
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();

// Request the configuration abstraction from the service provider.
// The default configurtion file and location is appsettings.json in the project root
IConfiguration config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

// Retrieve values from the config using their keys and target types.
int keyOneValue = config.GetValue<int>("KeyOne");
bool keyTwoValue = config.GetValue<bool>("KeyTwo");
string? keyThreeNestedValue = config.GetValue<string>("KeyThree:Message");

// Display the values on the console.
Console.WriteLine($"KeyOne = {keyOneValue}");
Console.WriteLine($"KeyTwo = {keyTwoValue}");
Console.WriteLine($"KeyThree:Message = {keyThreeNestedValue}");

// Application code that depends on the config can commence here.

await host.RunAsync();
```

```json
{
    "Settings": {
        "KeyOne": 1,
        "KeyTwo": true,
        "KeyThree": {
            "Message": "Oh, that's nice...",
            "SupportedVersions": {
                "v1": "1.0.0",
                "v3": "3.0.7"
            }
        },
        "IPAddressRange": [
            "46.36.198.121",
            "46.36.198.122",
            "46.36.198.123",
            "46.36.198.124",
            "46.36.198.125"
        ]
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
KeyOne = 1
KeyTwo = True
KeyThree:Message = Oh, that's nice...
```

As for a Windows Forms application, you can adapt a similar approach to implement the configuration dependency. Here's a link on how to implement dependency injection in a Win Forms application .NET 6.0 and .NET 7.0:

How to use dependency injection in WinForms in .Net 6.0 and 7.0
[How to use dependency injection in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70690219/1197553)

Answer (score -1):

Your main app(Primary app- **1st**) uses any **appsettings.json** and you need to use the same file in the called console app(Secondary app - **2nd**).

You can call the **2nd** with args

**1. The settings file from de primary program**
Located for example in "C:\appsettings.json"

```
{
  "AppName": "Value from main/primary/1st program AppSettings.json"
}
```

**2. Call from primary program**
You can send any filename with the arg **SettingsFile**

`dotnet .\CommandLineArgs.dll --SettingsFile=C:\appsettings.json`
or
`.\CommandLineArgs.exe --SettingsFile=C:\appsettings.json`

**3. The secondary program's code**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(args.Where(a => a.Contains("SettingsFile")).First().Split("=")[1], optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        IConfiguration config = builder.Build();
        Console.WriteLine(config.GetValue<string>("AppName"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output**
Simulating that powershell is the primary program. **Primary** sends the arg **SettingsFile** with value **C:\appsettings.json** to **Secondary**.
The secondary program add the json filename to configuration builder and builds configuration object.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

**References**

[Main() and command-line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line)
[Command-line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

██████████████████ ██████████████████

> **Another implementation**. You can check the code on https://github.com/JomaStackOverflowAnswers/CommandLineArgs

**PrimaryApp Code**
The primary app directory must contain the executable of secondary app. The primary app launches secondary with the args with settings filename.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{
    public async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("██ PrimaryApp Started");
        var secondaryAppExeFilename = Path.GetFullPath("SecondaryApp/SecondaryApp.exe");
        var settingsFilename = Path.GetFullPath("appsettings.json"); // var settingsFilename = Path.GetFullPath("C:\appsettings.json");
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = secondaryAppExeFilename;
        info.Arguments = $"--SettingsFile={settingsFilename}";
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = info;
        process.Start();
        await process.WaitForExitAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("█ PrimaryApp Exited");
    }
}
```

**SecondaryAppCode**
The secondary app capture the SettingsFilename arg from command line args and builds the configuration with this file.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("██ SecondaryApp Started");
        string settingsFile = args.Where(a => a.Contains("SettingsFile")).First().Split("=")[1];
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(settingsFile, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        IConfiguration config = builder.Build();
        Console.WriteLine($"SettingsFile: {settingsFile}");
        Console.WriteLine($"AppName value: {config.GetValue<string>("AppName")}");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("█SecondaryApp Exited");
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AppName": "PrimaryApp"
}
```

**Output**
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Nice idea, I think this would fail as I expect this app would need to be restarted by an end user. Yes, I could build a CMD file however some IT depts block CMD files all together for network security.

Comment: From primary app(.net app) you can invoke the secondary app with Process class - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0

Comment: how do you do this in DotNet6 (hint: there is no main method!)

Comment: @MC9000 check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements and check "the Implicit entry point method" section.